# C# WebBrowser Control very slow with network cable plugged

Tags: c#, web, browser, controls

I'm developing a simple C# application with a form with an embedded WebBrowser control. I create by myself the html files to be browsed, and put them in the temp folder. Then call the WebBrowser Navigate method, passing it the path of the current file to display.
My problem is that the first time I call this method (in the application startup) it takes about 30 seconds to display the page. Following navigation are ok.
The computer is connected to a switch in with another machine, implementing a very small network (2 Pc's). If I unplug the cable, even the first navigation (application startup) is fast.
I hope someone can help me.

Bye

Stefano

Comment: Do do access your files via file:/// or do you have some webserver? Maybe they contain some reference to a network location. While the cable is unplugged, the system checks there is no network and does not try to resolve them. When the cable is plugged in, there IS infact a network, so the browser tries to resolve the network reference, which fails after a timeout of 30 seconds.

Comment: thank you derpischer, well, I'm accessing the file in this way: webControl.Navigate("C:/temp/tmp.html"). In the html file there's the following header, but I already tried to remove it: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: Moreover, I got the same issue navigating to about:blank

Comment: I solved the problem by opening Internet Explorer, going to Internet Options, Connections, LAN Settings, uncheck the Automatically detect settings